# UriTemplate with period returns 404 in MVC Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, asp.net-mvc-3

I am hosting a WCF service in an MVC3 web application.  I have a method setup with a WebGet attribute with a UriTemplate. When the UriTemplate contains a period, I get a 404 response from the web server.

```
    [OperationContract, WebGet(UriTemplate = "DoSomething")]
    Stream DoWork();

http://localhost/Services/Service1.svc/DoSomething  - Works Correctly

    [OperationContract, WebGet(UriTemplate = "dummyfile.xml")]
    Stream DoWork();

http://localhost/Services/Service1.svc/dummyfile.xml - Returns a 404 error
```

I am guessing it has to do with routes, but I am not sure.  The routes I have setup right now are:

```
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.svc/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute( "Default", "{controller}/{action}/{id}",  new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

Can anyone provide some insight into how I can host a WCF service in a MVC3 app using a URITemplate with a period in it?

Comment: Phil Haack has [the answer](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/04/29/allowing-reserved-filenames-in-URLs.aspx)

Comment: @EdSF Why don't you add that comment as an answer, so that he can agree with you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the risk of plagiarism :) **Phil Haack** [has the answer](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/04/29/allowing-reserved-filenames-in-URLs.aspx)

Comment: Thanks.  This was definitely part of the problem.  Also the ASP.Net Development server does not like when you have periods in the URLs.